# Is it necessary to use GhostScript to compress pdf outputs of XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, ghostscript

I have tried to compress pdf outputs produced by XeLaTeX.

Is it necessary to use GhostScript to compress pdf outputs of XeLaTeX?

YES. It is necessary. See [Benchmark: xelatex v.s. latex-dvips-ps2pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20379/2099), there is a screenshot showing the file size there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if it makes things worse then no :-) In my experience, some PDFs produced by pdfTeX benefit from compression, while others do not. So I guess it depends on the exact internal nature. I've not tried the same with XeTeX, but would imagine that the same argument would apply.

Comment: Summary: PDFs produced by XeLaTeX benefit from compression.