# Is it possible to force auto-pst-pdf to use --hires option when it internally invokes pdfcrop?

Tags: pstricks, pdfcrop, auto-pst-pdf

### What is `--hires` for?

To obtain a better result when cropping a pdf image produced by PSTricks, I use `--hires` option as follows

```
latex filename.tex
dvips filename.dvi
ps2pdf -sOutputFile=filename-temp.pdf filename.ps
pdfcrop --hires filename-temp.pdf filename.pdf
```

According to `pdfcrop --help` shown in the following screenshot, the `--hires` make `pdfcrop` use high resolution bounding box (instead of the usual bounding box) to crop a pdf input.

[image]

### Scenario & Problem

I am writing  a book that use PDF, PNG, JPEG images and PSTricks codes. Actually `xelatex` can help me to compile the input file. Unfortunately, [`xelatex` runs very very very slowly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20379/2099). The very bad performance makes me reluctant to use `xelatex`.

The next candidates are `pdflatex` (and `context` but I am not familiar with it). Behind the scene, `pdflatex` with `auto-pst-pdf` package compiles each PSTrick code, converts it to PDF, crops the surrounding white space of the PDF image, and finally includes all the resulting PDF images to produce a complete document.
In this process, there is a temporary PDF file that contains a bunch of the cropped PDF images in the working directory. Unfortunately, the bounding box is not so accurate. If we see each cropped image carefully, we will notice that the left, right, top, and bottom margins are not exactly the same. Therefore, I need to pass `--hires` to `pdfcrop`, but I don't know how to do this.

The following code snippet might be needed for a test.

> Don't forget to use `-shell-escape` or `--enable-write18` when  invoking `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}% I need pass --hires, but how ?
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
\begin{pspicture}(4,3)
\pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,opacity=0.2](2,3){2}
\end{pspicture}
\caption{\label{fig:circle}This is a circle.}
\end{figure}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

### Question

Is it possible to force `auto-pst-pdf` to use `--hires` option when it internally invokes `pdfcrop`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\usepackage[...,
  pspdf={-dAutoRotatePages=/None}},
  pdfcrop={--hires}]{auto-pst-pdf}
```

Comment: @xport: that's a typo, I meant `ps2pdf`. `pspdf` is an own script.

Comment: @xport: ah, sure. Totally forget, that the keywords can't contain a digit in their names.

Comment: `-dAutoRotatePages=/None` is mandatory? If I ignore it, what is the problem?

Comment: When using ghostscript it can be sometimes too clever and rotates an images itself where it shouldn't be rotated