# XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX: which is faster?

Tags: xetex, luatex, performance

Beacuse I typeset in Japanese, I don't use LaTeX and now want to know which compiles faster: XeLaTeX or LuaTeX? Is Lua language allows to make the compile faster?

Comment: Related: [Why does XeLaTeX execute much much slower than latex-dvips-ps2pdf?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20379/5764), [Why does it take LuaLaTeX so long to load fonts and can I speed it up?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75118/5764)

Comment: Please ask questions that are to the point. The two first paragraphs of your post are not very relevant to your actual question.

Comment: It's okay if I just delete the two first paragraphs?

Comment: If the [answer from topskip](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75118/why-does-it-take-lualatex-so-long-to-load-fonts-and-can-i-speed-it-up) is still valid, the answer seems to be that LuaTeX may be many times slower - unless, perhaps, you use few and simple fonts with few features. @Werner: do you know if that answer *is* still current?

Comment: @cfr: I rarely use either XeLaTeX or Lua(La)TeX, sorry.