# xelatex slow with wallpaper package

Tags: xetex, pdf, wallpaper

I am using the wallpaper package to use pdf's as background

```
\ThisULCornerWallPaper{1}{firstpage.pdf}    
\ThisULCornerWallPaper{1}{lastpage.pdf}
```

Creating an output pdf file takes 6.5 seconds. I need to create ~1000/day and ~2 hours is to slow. Both my psd's are 100kb, without them the process takes 1.7 seconds to complete.

Before i benchmark and run multiple instances i liked to hear if any of you have experience with this and can provide any advice as to how I can speed up the process.

Comment: See [Why does xelatex execute much much slower than latex-dvips-ps2pdf?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20379/5764) and [XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX: which is faster?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201963/5764) Do you have to use XeLaTeX?

Comment: I am using XeLaTeX because of open truetype fonts. 
Haven't looked into LuaLaTeX, as XeLaTeX has preform well until now and still does when i don't use other pdfs as "wallpaper"